# Static SelectList asp.net MVC issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

What's I'm trying to create a select list with static items `model.satsList` and then selected Items will be set at `model.SelectedStatsList`

This is my Model :

```
    public class StatModel
{
        public IEnumerable<int> SelectedItemsRegion { set; get; }

        public IEnumerable<string> SelectedStatsList { get; set; } 
        public static List<SelectListItem> statList = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text="Request Number", Value="demandeR"},
                    new SelectListItem() { Text="agR", Value="agR"}  
                };                  
 }
```

My view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStatsList, Model.statList)
```

I get this error :

```
'pfebs0.Models.StatModel.statList' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basic C# usage issue. You are trying to access the static field `public static List statList` through an instance, namely the model that you have in the Razor view.

Simply replace this (model.SelectedStatsList):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStatsList, Model.statList)
```

With this (StatModel.SelectedStatsList):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStatsList, StatModel.statList)
```

Comment: the problem's in the Model.statList.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, I got the two mixed up (typo). So replace Model.statList with StateModel.statList. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

(One Solution)You can have a separate helper class in your project solution to handle the static data on your pages. for example:

//Helper.cs

> ```
> public Helper class(){
>   public static List<SelectListItem> GetStatList(){
>         return new List<SelectListItem>()
>             {
>                 new SelectListItem() {Text="Request Number", Value="demandeR"},
>                 new SelectListItem() { Text="agR", Value="agR"}  
>             };                  
>   } }
> ```

and in your controller class just bind this list to your Model class as below:

//MyController.cs

> ```
> public ActionResult MyModel(){
>    var model = new MyModel();
>    model.SelectedStatsList = Helper.GetStatList();
>    return View("MyView", model); 
> }
> ```

make sure you have a right property on your model class to set statlist above.
and in your view you will have:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStatsList, ... )

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your view code as below:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.SelectedStatsList,pfebs0.Models.StatModel.statList)
  // Assuming pfebs0.Models is the namespace for the StatModel
```

In C#, you cannot access static properties from an instance. In this case,property `Model` in the view is an instance of model that is being passed in.

In other words, you can access the static properties directly without creating an instance of an object.